# Can we have two mount_uploader for two different fields present in the same model and using the same carrierwave uploader file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I have a model Account where i want to have carrierwave uploader for two fields named logo and signature . I want to resize them with different size at the time of upload . Can i have those two in one uploader file ? For eg:- In my Account model can i have :-

```
mount_uploader :logo, AccountUploader
mount_uploader :signature, AccountUploader
```

And how do i write this in the AccountUploader to resize differently for different sizes . For logo i want to process as resize_to_fit to 100 x 100 and for signature to 200 x 100